# Weird IE behaviour getting index values jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing

I've got this mousedown function, to get the index value of its parent: div.combo_list, in Chrome and Firefox I get the good values that are zero based, like `0, 1, 2, 4...`

The strange thing is that IE8 gives me: `1, 3, 4...`

Does anybody know about or recognize this behaviour?

```
<div class="combo_list " style="width: 143px; display: none; ">
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">ex 1</div>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">ex 2</div>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">ex 3</div>
</div>


$("div.combo_list div").live("mousedown", function(){
            var nodeIndex = $(this).parent().index(); 
            alert ("" + nodeIndex); 
});
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML markup.

Comment: @patrick dw HTML markup added to the post thank

Comment: Could you give the entire HTML for the parent element of `div.combo_list`?

Comment: @lonesomeday <body> starts before the combo list why would you need that do? i'm traveling one parent up the tree

Comment: @user Because you're asking for the index of the `combo_list` compared to its sibling elements. It would be helpful to see those sibling elements...

Comment: Let me be a bit more specific, the siblings are all the same and added dynamically.

Comment: @user I'd love to see a live demo of this behavior ...

Comment: Hi Guys,

This wasn't a jQuery problem, another JS library dhtmlX was injecting different HTML to the DOM for IE browsers.

Thanks all for taking the time.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this bug reported for jQuery [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4274). It seems that IE might be attempting to add a new node into your HTML document. Try and run your site through an HTML validator